# ViewPager in scrollable Layout

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, commonsware-cwac

Is it possible to have a Viewpager with fragments and a flexible height `wrap_content` in a ScrollView or maybe in a ListView with MergeAdpater. For me both does not work, only the navigation tabs are displayed.

Comment: `ViewPager` definitely is not designed to go in a `ListView` row, let alone a `ViewPager` using fragments for its pages.

Comment: Also not in a ScrollView ?

Comment: I have never tried a `ViewPager` in a `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

`wrap_content` will not work for this.  You either need to specify a constant height or calculate the height and set it in code.

Comment: you sure if i change the height of the ScrollView after my fragments are drawn, works ?

Comment: i get the the fragment height in `OnGlobalLayoutListener()` with `getView().getWidth` but it's 0. How ould you calculate it ?

Comment: same effect when i add the viewpager later programaticly

Comment: I would need to know more specifics on what you're trying to accomplish before I could give any more guidance.  Could you provide some kind of wireframe showing what you're trying to do?